# jQuery in Master page is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

The simple jQuery alert wasn't called when i used it on Master/Content page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("test");
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is Head portion of my MasterPage

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Timekeeping System</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>    
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

**EDITED** Source Code

```
<head><title>
</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /><link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("test");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Did you check the source code? Is it how you expect? It might be hint for solution.

Comment: Just a suggestion to correct your tag <script type="text/javascript"../>

Comment: @AliK-What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check .js file path, 
if you can't sure, maybe include offical .js file like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed jQuery on the MasterPage

Instead of

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Like this

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have different sub folders pages this is what I run.
    ' type="text/javascript">

```
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js")%>' type="text/javascript">   </script>
```

This allows ASP.Net to resolve the url for me.